# How To Get SpUSer Object From UserProfile?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, user-profile, user-profile-property

Need To Get SpUser LoginName

My References Code:-

```
using (var site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Web.Url))
            {


                SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(site);
                var profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);

                    var configProperties = new ConfigurationProperties();

                    var spUsers = site.RootWeb.SiteUsers.Cast<SPUser>().ToList();

                foreach (UserProfile userProfile in profileManager)
                {


                    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the login name from the user profile as illustrated below:

```
  foreach (UserProfile userProfile in profileManager)
  {
    string loginName = userProfile["AccountName"][0] as string;
    Console.WriteLine(loginName);
  }
```